# How to export Image of my form c#

Tags: c#, printscreen

I need a solution how could i make a Print Screen of my WinForm on C# and export it as PNG.

Bests

Comment: Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but it is literally a print-screen of your app... <a href="http://blog.coryfoy.com/2005/04/screen-print-capture-in-c-using-sendinput/">The solution is detailed in this blog post</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this [blog post](http://blog.codeconsults.com/post/2008/03/WinForms-screen-capture.aspx) will help.

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ParentForm.Size.Width, ParentForm.Size.Height))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
      g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(ParentForm.DesktopLocation.X, ParentForm.DesktopLocation.Y), new Point(0, 0), ParentForm.Size);
    }

    bitmap.Save(@"C:\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: If the window doing this isn't the frontmost, won't this copy whatever might be in front of it?

Comment: thanks a lot ,that helped and worked after doin a lot of search .But as cHao is saying if Form is not TopMost it will not work ,what means if i minimize the Form that will print only a black square .

Comment: Yep, I just tried it.  I think the form needs to be active for this trick to work.  So this will work fine if you add a button to your form that copies the screen, but if you want to capture a different form or with a shortcut key, you will probably need to use a different mechanism to capture.

Comment: well i need to do that Automatically ,and i`m playing with WindowsFormState when i need to export ,so that's OK For me ,it's working and im enjoining the Quality .Bests

Answer (score 1):

Never tried it, but i'd think you should be able to call `OnPaint(args)` with a PaintEventArgs you create, that includes a Graphics for the image you want to draw on, and the ClipRectangle encompassing the whole area of the form.

This would only work if your form properly processes paint messages (ie: if it stores enough info to be able to repaint the window fully at will), and it may only get the client area (ie: it might not get the title bar or menus).